# Problem with Firebase Image Resize extension

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-extensions

I installed the Firebase Image Resize extension,i upload an image to test it and it created the file but it keeps loading and it doesnt give me the url of the image.

I waited for 10 mins and is still the same, what could be the problem?

[image]